# PhpStorm type-hinting for factories?

Tags: factory, phpstorm, type-hinting

I have code more or less like this:

```php
class Foo {
    public static function factory($str) {
        $class = "Foo_" . $str;
        return new $class;
    }
}
class Foo_Bar {
    public function razzle() {
        print "Foo_Bar->baz() was called";
    }
}

$Obj = Foo::factory('Bar');
```

and I would like PhpStorm to understand that `$Obj` is a `Foo_Bar` object, so that for example if I type `$Obj->raz`, `razzle()` will show up for autocompletion.

Is there any way to get this?  To tell PhpStorm that the function `Foo::factory($str)` returns an object of type `Foo_$str`?  My guess is that the answer is no.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you **can** do this if your factory is a static method. It should work fine for the examples you have provided.

**More details** and some basic example can be found here: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.  I'm using PhpStorm 6.0.3.  I've created the following two files in a new empty project: http://pastie.org/8146899, but I don't get any kind of autocomplete on ``$x->...`

Comment: Work for me. 1) File with metadata MUST be named `.phpstorm.meta.php`; 2) It will not be picked up instantly -- close and re-open the project (search for such file is done on project load; once file is found, changes to it should be picked up immediately) -- this behaviour was fixed in v7.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't realize the name was required, it works beautifully now.

Comment: @Sorcy Appears as though the static call key now works for both static and instance method calls as of a few months ago, according to the page LazyOne linked.

Comment: @AdrianGünter Nice - I'll have to try it on one of our projects.

Answer (score 13):

As far as I know you can't make PHPStorm understand what Foo is giving out, because it is dynamic. However you can surely tell PHPStorm what your $Obj variable is, by putting a doc comment above it, like so:

```
/** @var Foo_Bar $Obj */
$Obj = Foo::factory('Bar');
```

Comment: This lets PhpStorm know about $Obj's dataype, but what I want is for PhpStorm to know about the return datatype of Foo::factory() -- I don't want PhpDoc @var's every time I use a factory, that's just an ugly hack.  LazyOne's reply sounded promising, but I can't seem to get it to work; I suspect I'm missing a step.

Comment: @hobbit.trap *"that's just an ugly hack"* -- it is not. PHPDoc itself has no mechanism of providing dynamic return type (build from actual string parameter value). If it's not in actual Doc standard (which is used for code hinting), why do you expect this to be magically working?

Comment: @LazyOne As you note, PHPDoc doesn't have this mechanism built-in.  Certainly then any PHPDoc-based solution will be, necessarily, a hack.  But I wasn't looking for a PHPDoc solution, I was looking for any PhpStorm solution -- which you provided above, many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You should use phpstorm metadata, that works for both dynamic and static calls.

```
class Foo {
    public function factory($str) {
        $class = "Foo_" . $str;
        return new $class();
    }
}
class Foo_Bar {
    public function baz() {
        print "Foo_Bar->baz() was called";
    }
}

$Obj = Foo->factory('Bar');
$Obj->baz();
```

create a file in your project root directory and name it `.phpstorm.meta.php`:

```
<?php

namespace PHPSTORM_META {
    $STATIC_METHOD_TYPES = [
        \Foo::factory('') => [
            "Bar" instanceof \Foo_Bar,
        ],
    ];
}
```

thanks @LazyOne for link.

Comment: so awkward and cumbersome.

might as well just use `/* @return ClassA|ClassB|ClassC */` right in your class/method without having to touch meta data files, all hidden and hardly portable and not committed to the repo.

Comment: @ahnbizcad It's powerful for non-trivial methods. Also, the file doesn't need to reside in your repo. I put mine in a different directory and added the directory to my project.

Answer (score 0):

One way which worked for me is to explicitly list in an "or" list all of the possible classes the factory might spit out.

```php
/**
 * @param $str
 * @return Foo_Bar | Foo_Cad | Foo_Dad
 */
class Foo {
    public static function factory($str) {
        $class = "Foo_" . $str;
        return new $class;
    }
}
```

But this does mean all the method type hinting on the instance/object will have the union of all of the listed classes.

Not perfect, but still better than nothing, and still better than having to write `/* @var ClassA */` multiple times on every instance it occurs.

Answer (score -1):

One way is to explicitly list in an "or" list all of the possible classes the factory might spit out.

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->

/**
 * @param $str
 * @return Foo_Bar | Foo_Baz | Foo_Cad
 */
class Foo {
    public static function factory($str) {
        $class = "Foo_" . $str;
        return new $class;
    }
}
```