# PhpStorm type hinting for derived class return value

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc, type-hinting

Is it possible to hint PhpStorm that in the code below return value of `item()` method has the type `DOMElement` (**WITHOUT modifying the actual PHP statements**, i.e. by some external setting of PhpStorm or plugin or using PHPDoc comment of some sort, etc.)?

Again, please, don't suggest me to **modify the statements in the code**, in particular the part `$list->item(0)->getAttribute('test')`.

Also, I found a somewhat similar question [PhpStorm type-hinting for factories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666699/phpstorm-type-hinting-for-factories) but it deals with type-hinting for user-defined functions, in my case the function `item()` is a predefined library function.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML('<x test="123"/>');
$list = $doc->getElementsByTagName('x');
if($list->length > 0)
    var_dump($list->item(0)->getAttribute('test'));
```

[image: PhpStorm warning]

Comment: Just to get this right: you can't change any of the code you have listed above? Or you can't change the implementation of the item(0) call?

Comment: @nivekastoreth Only whitespace can be changed - that includes adding comments which are a subcase of whitespace.

Comment: Fixed in strubs. https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs
External Libraries -> PHP Runtime -> Advanced Settings -> Default strubs path: C:\User\Name\<from git downloaded code>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Accordingly to [official docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) `$list->item(0)` returns element of `DOMNode` class which does NOT have `getAttribute()` method. PhpStorm follows official docs here.

But if you add extra line into youe code and analyze it in debugger (e.g. `$z = $list->item(0);`), you will see that `$z` is instance of `DOMElement` that **has** such method.

---

**A.** You cannot add documentation to predefined methods (especially in a chain) on the fly. No way.

**B.** As you can see -- the "problem" here is in the docs: they say that `item()` returns instance of one class while in your particular case it returns instance of different class.

---

Few options:

**1.** Modify your code to introduce intermediate variable to which you can give correct type hint. *As I understand you do not want to use it.*

**2.** Ignore these warnings: you could disable it completely or for just that file; you could lower the severity (e.g. "info" instead of "warning") etc

**3.** Alter documentation (not sure if this is a good idea though).

This could be done on global level by modifying actual stub file (part of PhpStorm distribution... so it will affect ALL projects and you will have to redo this after upgrading to a newer version again).

Or you can do this on local level (for this project only):

- extract stub for `DOMNodeList` class from original stub file
- place it in separate file anywhere in your project
- alter `@return` tag of `item()` method -- make it `@return DOMElement` of whatever you require there.

This will make IDE "merging" docs from two sources: sort of `@return DOMNode|DOMElement`.

Once again -- this will cover your particular case -- how this will affect your other cases I cannot tell.

Comment: The extracting the stub file I hadn't thought of, that's pretty clever - although I think I would reject that code review if someone sent it to me since that could lead to misleading documentation if the PHP version changed.

Comment: Well .. this is done for IDE only -- such file does not need to be necessarily included in actual code base of your project (which also means: instead of placing such file in actual project just link it: either via additional content root or include paths).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by not being able to edit the PHP statements but at the same time being able to edit PHPDoc comments, but you can accomplish what you asked for by doing the following:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML('
<x test="123"/>');
$list = $doc->getElementsByTagName('x');
if($list->length > 0) {
    /** @var DomElement $element */
    $element = $list->item(0);
    var_dump($element->getAttribute('test'));
}
```

But this is not technically safe since getElementsByTagName returns a DomNodeList which specifies that it contains DomNodes (although I'm not familiar enough to know if for all practical purposes the list will only contain DomElements)

Either way, when I look at this example code, the methods being used are already properly documented, your issue is you're trying to specify, as stated above, special constraints that are not enforced (specifically) in the DOM code/comments.

Comment: This is exactly what I did not want to do - splitting the `$list->item(0)->getAttribute('test')` into several parts and introducing new variable.

Comment: Figured you might say that. You only said list() was predefined, not that the code calling $list->item() was unmodifiable as well.