# PHP hint dynamic return type (based on $class param)

Tags: php, autocomplete, type-hinting

Is it possible that you hint the returned type of a PHP function/method, determined by one if it's arguments? Something like this:

```
/**
 * @param string $class
 * @param array $attributes
 * @return $class <- this doesn't work
 */
public function create($class, $attributes) {
    ... // finally returns object of type $class
}
```

I'm implementing a library that allows to create factory objects for unit tests. So I want to make it possible in the client code to have:

```
$user = $factory->create('Users', ['name' => 'John', 'email' => 'john@example.com']);
```

And have autocompletion of object methods/attributes without having to add explicit PHPDoc comments in the client code like this:

```
/* @var $user Users */
$user = $factory->create('Users', ['name' => 'John', 'email' => 'john@example.com']);
```

Any suggestions are most welcome! As long as I get it working in popular IDEs (PHPStorm, Eclipse, NetBeans), it's a valid solution.

Comment: No - and I don't see any reason to do that. PHPDoc/typehints are intended to add strict bounds to the code. That is - method or function should have exactly one return type (at most, that return type or null), because it is an independent piece of code and it knows nothing about the context, in which it will be used

Comment: I want to hint the IDE about the return type, so I can use auto-completion, not add any validation of it.

Comment: Yes, you can do this. The question is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17671992/540001

Answer (score 2):

Try [DynamicReturnTypePlugin](https://github.com/pbyrne84/DynamicReturnTypePlugin). then you can add this configuration manually