# Autocomplete dynamic declared method

Tags: php, phpstorm

How do I get my IDE to register that this method is returning a instance of the parameter?

So I could do something like this:

```
Class::models()->getModel('newModel')->newModelMethodHere()?
```

The code works, but not the autocomplete in PHPStorm.

```
    /**
     * Returns the object of the model
     *
     * @var $this->_models[$model] $model
     * @param string object $model
     * @throws Exception
     * @return object
     */
    public function getModel($model)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($model, $this->_models) && class_exists($model) && is_object($this->_models[$model])
            && $this->_models[$model] instanceof $model) {
            if (is_a($this->_models[$model], $model)) {
                /* @var $this->_models[$model] $model */
                return ($this->_models[$model]);
            }
        }
        throw new Exception('Model ' . (string)$model . ' is not registered correctly.');
    }
```

Comment: Metadata should help (it made just for such cases): https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata http://stackoverflow.com/q/17666699/783119

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change my code a bit, but I managed to get this to work:

```
namespace PHPSTORM_META {
    $STATIC_METHOD_TYPES = array(
       \ClassName::getModel('') => [
           "" == "@",
       ],
   );
}
```

in a new .phpstorm.meta.php file in the root of my project in PHPStorm.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your comment block. The return should clarify what object returns.

```
 /**
 * Returns the object of the model
 * ...
 * @return ModelNameClass
 */
```

Comment: Nope. The function can return different objects. All depending on the $model parameter

Comment: Well then you'll have to define all the possible return objects:

`* @return ModelNameClass|AnotherNameClass|ThirdClass`

Or an interface that all of your classes implement.

Comment: `
namespace PHPSTORM_META
{
    $STATIC_METHOD_TYPES = array(
        \ClassName::models()->getModel('') => [
            "RoutingUri" instanceof \RoutingUri,
            "" == "@",
        ],
    );
}`

I was reading that this should work. But Three-level method doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

The method `getModel()` probably returns objects of different types depending on the provided argument. While this is not good practice, there is a simple trick that you can use to let PhpStorm help you with the auto complete: store the value returned by `getModel()` into a variable and use a `@var` annotation to tell PhpStorm about its type:

```
 /** @var newModel $model */
 $model = Class::models()->getModel('newModel');
 // Here PhpStorm will be able to help you with its auto-complete
 $model->newModelMethodHere()?
```